# For two independent events $A$ and $B$, find $P(A \cap B^c|A \cup B) $

Tags: probability

For two independent events $A$ and $B$, find $P(A \cap B^c|A \cup B)$.
Futhermore, we know the probability $P(A)$=0.4 and $P(A\cup B)$=0.5.

I thought that since $$P(A|B)= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)},$$ I can also say that
$$P(A\cap B^c| A \cup B)=\frac{P((A\cap B^c)\cap (A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}.$$ Now my question is the following: Since (I thought that) $(A\cap B^c)\subset (A\cup B)$, is it correct to say that $P((A\cap B^c) \cap (A\cup B))=P(A\cap B^c)$ and therefore that

$$P(A\cap B^c| A \cup B)=\frac{P(A\cap B^c)}{P(A\cup B)}$$

Comment: Probabilities are numbers, not sets (events).

Comment: I think I've edited my question correctly now?

Comment: Partially. You have an intersection of probabilites which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Indeed the identity 
$$P(A\cap B^c\mid A \cup B)=\frac{P(A\cap B^c)}{P(A\cup B)}$$ is correct. Note that the question in the title and the question in the post differ.

Comment: I've made another edit. If it is still not right, would you maybe correct the parts which aren't written correctly, I don't see any other mistakes?

Comment: If A and B are independent then $A$ and $B^c$ are independent. Therefore $P(A \cap B^c)=P(A) \cdot P(B^c)$

Comment: It is indeed correct to say that. You are on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
And since this is correct, and $P(A \cap B^c) = P(A)*P(B^c)$ where $$P(A \cup B)=P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B) - P(A)*P(B)$$
we can find the value of $P(B)=\frac{1}{6}$.
Thus we have the final solution
$$P(A\cap B^c| A \cup B)=\frac{P(A\cap B^c)}{P(A\cup B)}=\frac{P(A)P(B^c)}{0.5}=\frac{0.4*(1-\frac{1}{6})}{0.5}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: The route is okay. I am too lazy to check your calculations.

Comment: You answer is completely correct.